# In shell, how to judge a string start with a path name?

Tags: regex, string, shell

I want to write like :
    `if [[ ${path} = /home/* ]]`

but it doesn't work. So how can I do it correctly？

Comment: Which shell language is this?  I was thinking bash, but the braces make it look like some sort of expression language.

Comment: Using bash, if there is no "/" in string, it's OK. But the path contains "/", so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Makoto `$foo` is equivalent to `${foo}` and the braces are defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_002_003).

Comment: Works for me, can you define "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `bash`, you could write

```
if [ ${path#/home/} != ${path} ]; then
  echo "Yes, it's a home dir"
fi
```

The logic: `${path#/home/}` will cut `/home/` from the beginning of `path` *if it is there*, or will return it as is if `path` does not start with `/home/`.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example.

```
● path='/home/xxx/Ubuntu One/www'; if [ -d "`dirname "$path"`" ]; then echo YES; fi
YES
```

and also you have better use $HOME or ${HOME} to fetch home dir path.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this question `regex`, but you are not using a regular expression, you are using *globbing*.  Which is fine, and your example works for me:

```
path='/home/user1/bin'

if [[ ${path} = /home/* ]]
then
    echo "$path matched"
else
    echo "$path did not match"
fi
```

(although I prefer to use == rather than plain =).  Can you show you code (with an example path) so we can check?  Are you sure you are using bash?

If you want to use a regular expression, then use the *match* operator `=~`, for example:

```
if [[ ${path} =~ ^/home/ ]]
```

The `^` means "startswith", there is no need for the `*`.